# what prepare for app means in itunes connect

Tags: ios, itunes

I have just finished my first app and finished all the instructions I have seen so ao to upload it to iTunes. Now, I see in the `Itunes>Manage Your Application`

```
Version1.0
Status  Prepare for Upload
Date CreatedSep 23, 2012
```

next to the app icon.

Do I have to do anything else or it just waits approval from apple?

I know that this is not a programming question but I did't know where to aski and googling for it gave me nothing.

I have found that  prepare for upload means that:

```
Prepare for Upload (Yellow) 
Appears as the first status for your app. This status means that you should enter or edit metadata, screenshots, pricing, In-App Purchases, Game Center, iAd network settings, etc., to prepare your app for upload to the App Store.
```

but I have submitted add data and screenshots. How can I proceed to the next level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preparing an app for submission means configuring its metadata , or related in app purchases or if its a game then configuring game center , so once you are over with developing your app then you are ready to submit it to the iTunes app store review . so in your case you can follow the [this](http://www.slideshare.net/nefairious/ansca-app-store-presentation) link to upload your app to the app store. hope this would help.